# String.toUpperCase may strip accents or not

Tags: java

I have to apply `toUpperCase` on a name that may contain accents ("é", "à", etc.).
Problem:

- with JUnit, `"é".toUpperCase` converts to "E", the accent is removed
- in my application (a Spring REST API), "é".toUpperCase converts to "É". The input comes from an Ember frontend, but the encoding is the same (UTF-8)

JUnit tests and Spring application use the same characters set (UTF-8) and the locale is French. Both running on Oracle Java 8, on the same machine (Jenkins CI on Debian, but I can reproduce this behavior on my computer: Windows 7).
I tried to specify the locale `toUpperCase(Locale.FRANCE)`, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Are you aware of something that may explain this difference?

Comment: As mentioned by @freedev, I too have the no problem with the uppercase of string with accent. I also tried with toUpperCase(Locale.FRANCE) and still no problem. Are you using JUnit 4?

Comment: Had you tried to print your default locale ?

Comment: @Paolo Forgia I use TestNG, but I can reproduce with Junit 4.

Comment: @freedev my default locale is "fr_FR". I tried to insert Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr_FR")); but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the conversation with @JonathanLermitage this is not a Java problem but is related to the embedded database (h2) used in the unit tests that is not correctly configured.

---

I'm using Java 8, no particular configuration.

```
  @Test
  public void test()
  {
    String a = "àòùìèé";
    String b = a.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(b);

    System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
    assertEquals(b,"ÀÒÙÌÈÉ");
  }
```

Returns

```
ÀÒÙÌÈÉ
en_US
```

Comment: (sorry, I'm new on Stackoverflow and I encounter some problem pasting this output)

Comment: My edit is refused since some code is not formatted. Meanwhile, I think I have understood the problem: actually, my string is (correctly!) converted to uppercase, persisted to PostgreSQL (via Spring Data), then read: my PostgreSQL seems to need some configuration since it drops accents on capitalized letters. Sorry, I was wrong when I said unit test case doesn't upperCase correctly, the mistake was on my application's code.

Comment: Oops, I'm very sorry: this is not PostgreSQL but my embedded database (h2) that is not correctly configured. It explains why the production application (that uses PostgreSQL) works fine, but my unit test are buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once and it was fixed for me by setting the default Locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr_FR"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I simply inserted 
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr_FR")); 
before toUppercase invocation. Should I use it somewhere else ?